Cartoon show Japanese with 2 (male and female) heroes and 3 villians
I remember watching this Japanese cartoon 10-12 years ago. It had two main heroes, a male and a female, that dressed in bird-like costumes.  They are shown in constant battles against three villains: a female and her two silly male sidekicks.
The villains always lose, and they always get destroyed in this mushroom-cloud, which also serves as a running gag of the series.
The mushroom cloud always looks similar to this picture here:


For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I would say for sure that it was Yatterman. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yatterman)

Mechas
Yatter-Wan (ヤッターワン Yattā-Wan)
Voiced by: Masaru Ikeda (1977–1979), Kōichi Yamadera (2008)
The dog-shaped robot Yatter-Wan was designed by Gan's father as a prototype rescue robot. It is fitted with a siren and a bell, similar to other rescue vehicles, and a joystick to control the other features. Its nostrils fire iron pellets, and holds two fire hoses on its back. A bone-shaped power pack, known as "Mecha-Tonic", is fed to the dog robot to allow a sudden outburst of strength to ward off a deadly blow. The robot's special attack is a large group of miniature robots, usually taking the shape of land-based animals, exit the robots mouth. The mini-robots use their weapons on the enemy, causing the Doronbo's robots to explode and create a skull-shaped explosion cloud.

